# Disable SSH connections over HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssl, curl, github

I was trying to git push my RoR app to Heroku at another company which had a firewall blocking SSH connection. So I followed the guide here: https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/ and added to `~/.ssh/config`, the following code:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

`ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com` and `ssh -T git@github.com` were ran successfully and I was able to git push my app over the corporate firewall. However, back at home, when I tried git push again, my RoR app crashed on Heroku. I am getting this error when I try to install anything on Homebrew: `LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443`. I think this error and app crashing is related to the SSH over HTTPS change I made. I upgraded OSX from Yosemite to High Sierra - not sure if that's related.

Please help disable SSH connections over HTTPS.

Edit 1: running `ssh -vT git@github.com` gives the following output, if this helps:

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, LibreSSL 2.5.4
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/rahn/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/rahn/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/rahn/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/rahn/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh_0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/rahn/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/rahn/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.253.113]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi sampbay! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3484, received 2104 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 33097.5, received 19987.7
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Just remove the code you put into that file?

Comment: I tried it but still gives `LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443` error... I can't even brew install anything because of that error when installing through https source.

Comment: did you look at .git/config file? Could you print its contents here?